# Fade images in and out randomly in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am having a problem where I need to fade in and out 6 random images on a page every second a new image appears. I have tried the code I found online but it only fades in one image in a random location and doesn't fade in/out others. Please if you could help me, I would really appreciate it.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(showLetter);
    var imgsArray = ["backgroundI1", "backgroundI2", "backgroundI3", "backgroundI4", "backgroundI5", "backgroundI6"];

    function generateRandomForArray() {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
        return num;
    }

    function generateRandom() {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
        return num;
    }


    function showLetter() {
        var name = imgsArray[generateRandomForArray()];
        $(".heroBackground").append("<img src='media/backgroundImages/" + name + ".png'>");
        var left = generateRandom();
        var top = generateRandom();
        $(".heroBackground").last().css({ "position": "absolute", "top": top + "px", "left": left + "px" });
    }
```

Again thank you!

Comment: Try removing `.last()` from the last line. If that doesn't work, please post the relevant HTML.

Comment: your code shown here is not complete. what is `heroBackground` html element and also your css for fade in/out?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, using css for animations, and a tiny javascript snippet to reset the animation because of that pesky limitation in css where you can't have a delay in the animation repeat.

By doing it this way you might run the risk that the interval time runs async sometimes to the image slider(a little to late) if you have heavy long looped other javascripts running and will only restart when the other thing is finished.

But on the other hand you can use fancy css3 transitions and don't need to manage the timings in javascript.

```js
/**
 *  replace with your own function that supplies array of random images.
 */
function getRandomImages() {
   var random = ['https://i.imgur.com/Y7icJAN.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/IX9YUcq.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/8p6P3gN.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/bAglKHW.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/VG0nBdD.jpg','https://i.imgur.com/vkUNuCx.jpg'];
   
   return random;
}
/** apply random images **/
var images = getRandomImages();
$('.hero .background').each(function(index, elem) {
   $(this).css({'background-image':"url('" + images[index] + "')"});
});
resetAnimationOnHeroes();

function resetAnimationOnHeroes() {
    var heroes = $('.hero .background');
  heroes.css({'animation':'none'});
  /** need timeout here so browser will not see all javascript changes as one instruction and only apply the last one **/
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    heroes.css({'animation':''});
  },10);
}
window.setInterval(resetAnimationOnHeroes, (15 * 1000) + 250);
```

```css
.hero {
  width: 100%;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
}
.hero .background {
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 200px;
  animation: fadeHero 3s linear;
  
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
}
.hero .background:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0s;
    
}
.hero .background:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 2.5s;
    
}
.hero .background:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 5s;
    
}
.hero .background:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 7.5s;
    
}
.hero .background:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 10s;
    
}
.hero .background:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: 12.5s;
    
}

@keyframes fadeHero {
  0% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  25% {
     opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity:1; 
  }
  100% {
     opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="background"></div>
</div>
```